# What are some good security audit tools for PHP web applications?

Tags: linux, php, security

I'm interested in finding open-source tools for auditing some PHP code I didn't write, before putting it into production. I'll need black-box HTTP-probing scanners as well as static code parsers/analyzers.

Where can I find a good comprehensive list of all such tools, and a smaller list of which ones are actually worth trying?

Here's a start. I haven't tried any of them:

- ratproxy http://code.google.com/p/ratproxy/
- pixy http://www.dragoslungu.com/2007/10/30/pixy-is-a-free-php-code-audit-tool/
- Spike PHP http://developer.spikesource.com/projects/phpsecaudit

Comment: My similar question was closed but this one has been okay for 14 years? https://serverfault.com/questions/1157088/what-are-some-good-nginx-rate-limits-for-wordpress-websites

Comment: Maybe it's the slightly different wording? A "comprehensive list" is a factual finite dataset which is not opinion based. TBH I'm just as baffled as you. I've had other questions closed that were much less defiant than this one.

Answer (score 1):

[Backtrack 4](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) has a bunch of web app testing and fuzzing tools included with it.  So I tend to start with the tool found on it.  In the past I have had good luck with [W3AF](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/) identifying problems in apache and php.ini configurations as well as the PHP apps that I've inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Having done both source and blackbox auditing before, I'm inclined to recommend Acunetix or IBM's Hailstorm. As previously mentioned, W3AF is a very good piece of software. But none of these pieces of software are nearly as good as doing it yourself.